# How do I capitalize random parts of a sentence?

Tags: python

I have trouble programming with Python. I have to write long sentences where there are capitalization in random parts of the sentence. These are the sentences:

```
ülenurme vald. 
ülenurme vald asub tartu maakonnas ja jääb tartu linnast vahetult lõunasse.
ülenurme sai oma nime 17. sajandi alguses rajatud ülenurme mõisalt.
vallas asub ka tartu lennujaam, mille juures tegutseb eesti lennuakadeemia.
```

And i have to make it into this:

```
ÜLENURME VALD. 
Ülenurme vald asub Tartu maakonnas ja jääb Tartu linnast vahetult lõunasse.
Ülenurme sai oma nime 17. sajandi alguses rajatud Ülenurme mõisalt.
Vallas asub Tartu lennujaam, mille juures tegutseb Eesti Lennuakadeemia.
```

But the question is how????? I´m new in programming and just started out, so if someone could help me id be very thankful.

Comment: What is your own attempt? Can you post your current approach?

Comment: By random do you mean truly random, as in you have no choice in the matter, or do you just mean arbitrary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to start with, Python has a method called [`capitalize()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_capitalize.htm). Your first sentence is in all caps so you could do [`upper()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_upper.htm) on that one.

If you have specific words which should always be capitalized, you can set a variable to a list of words, then split your string, and iterate over it with a `for` loop, checking each word if it's contained in that variable.

```
capitalize_bank = ['ülenurme', 'tartu', 'eesti', "lennuakadeemia", "vallas"]

a = "vallas asub ka tartu lennujaam, mille juures tegutseb eesti lennuakadeemia"
a_new = ' '.join([s.capitalize() if s in capitalize_bank else s for s in a.split()])

print(a_new) 

# >> Vallas asub ka Tartu lennujaam, mille juures tegutseb Eesti Lennuakadeemia
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i figured it out now. This community is really great :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do completely "randomly", but not very efficiently:

```
def randomlyMakeUpperCase(passage, numCharsToUpper):
    for i in range(numCharsToUpper):
        randIndex = random.randint(0, len(passage) - 1)
        passage = passage[:randIndex] + passage[randIndex].upper() + passage[randIndex+1:]
    return passage
```

You'd run it like this:

```
passage = "this is a very long string and it goes on and on"
passage = randomlyMakeUpperCase(passage, 10)
```

It's also missing checks for upper casing the same characters multiple times and upper casing characters that don't have an upper case (like spaces).

Although looking at your example above, it looks like you want to simply upper-case some words? Or maybe specific words?